# Upload a file to azure blob storage met an error using java

Tags: java, azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm new to azure ,I want to upload a file in azure using java sdk and met with error.

Here is my approach,

```
BlobServiceClient client = new BlobServiceClientBuilder()
    .connectionString(connectStr)
    .buildClient();

BlobContainerClient blobContainerClient = blobServiceClient.createBlobContainer(containerName);

String localPath = "./data/";
String fileName = "quickstart" + java.util.UUID.randomUUID() + ".txt";

BlobClient blobClient = blobContainerClient.getBlobClient(fileName);
FileWriter writer = null;
try
{
    writer = new FileWriter(localPath + fileName, true);
    writer.write("Hello, World!");
    writer.close();
}
catch (IOException ex)
{
    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
}

blobClient.uploadFromFile(localPath + fileName);
```

exception,

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.illegalArgumenatation:Input byte array has wrong 4-byte ending unit
> at java.base/java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode0(Base64.java:837)

Kindly help with this?

Comment: Hi @Sensei sai please refer this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-java?tabs=powershell%2Cmanaged-identity%2Croles-azure-portal%2Csign-in-azure-cli

Comment: I'm following the same document and met an error

Comment: Can you show the full stack trace? Somewhere there's base64 decoding, but I don't see it in your code. Maybe the connection string is invalid; I did a quick check, and the account key inside it does seem to be base64.

Comment: yeah,Rob spoor it is connection string problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I tried in my environment and successfully uploaded files in azure blob storage.**

```
package  com.blobs.quickstart;

import  com.azure.storage.blob.*;
import  com.azure.storage.blob.BlobServiceClient;

public  class  App

{
public  static  void  main( String[] args )
{
String  connectStr = "<Connection string>";
BlobServiceClient  blobServiceClient = new  BlobServiceClientBuilder().connectionString(connectStr).buildClient();
String  containerName = "test";
BlobContainerClient  containerClient = blobServiceClient.getBlobContainerClient(containerName);
String  localPath = "C:\\Users\\v-vsettu\\Documents\\Venkat\\barcode.docx";
BlobClient  blobClient = containerClient.getBlobClient("barcode.docx");
System.out.println("Blob uploaded");
blobClient.uploadFromFile(localPath);
}
}
```

**Console:**
[image]

**Portal:**

[image]

Initially, I got an same error :

[image]
Because when I pass wrong connection string or access key in the code I got an error. Make sure you are connection string is in correct.

**You can get the connection string from portal:**

[image]

**Reference:**
[Quickstart: Azure Blob Storage library - Java | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-java?tabs=powershell%2Cmanaged-identity%2Croles-azure-portal%2Csign-in-azure-cli)

Comment: Thanks Venkatesan for brief explanation. yeah, you are correct.